# How to properly shutdown Windows while MongoDB is running

Tags: shutdown

I am using Mongodb version 3.2.6 as my application database.  MongoDB is installed as a SYSTEM service in Windows and my application runs in Kiosk mode.  When shutting the system down by performing a clean Windows shutdown process, I am getting error in event log showing unexpected shutdown of mongo.  I also see in the logs that journaling is running and recovering the database every time.

I first attempted to add a log off script via gpedit using "net stop mongo db"

After learning that this is not a good method, I changed to "mongo admin --eval shutdownServer()".  I am continuing to get mdmp files and seeing journaling performing recovery.

Any advice? A colleague believes this is a bug in MongoDB.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973113/how-to-stop-mongodb-server-on-windows

Comment: Haven't seen that post, however i am doing as recommended with mongo admin --eval shutdownServer().  However I think by shutting down, windows is terminating the service before my batch is called.  Trying to figure out a way to confirm this is happening.  Running the batch manual prior to shutdown does not create mdmp and journaling doesn't occur.
I'll check out some of the other suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: I added a createvent to my batch. This runs 1 to 2 seconds before windows terminates the service which is not ample time to safely stop mongo.  Have tried setting the WaitToKillService registry entry to a higher number but nothing has changed. 

Running the batch manual prior to shutdown does not create mdmp and journaling doesn't occur.
Thanks!